# generating logs of simple java class with log4j api

Tags: java, log4j

I have one query is that if I write a simple Java class and I want to see the logs that are executed at the behind, such that are executed at the backend by the JVM. I have log4j JAR with me. Could you please give me advice to how to achieve this?

I would to see the same logs that are generated in case of a WebApp, so I can reuse it for a Java App.

Answer (score 3):

try looking at log4j api/demo  here http://www.vaannila.com/log4j/log4j-tutorial/log4j-tutorial.html

you can generate log for any class and any application afaik using log4j , which needs not necessarily be a web app

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple [example](http://www.vaannila.com/log4j/log4j-configuration.html) that you should be able to adapt to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If your "simple Java class" happens to be in a Java EE container (like a .jsp or servlet in Tomcat, JBoss or WebSphere), then all you need to do is:

1) import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

2) declare a static instance in your class:

```
 EXAMPLE:  `static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger ("MyApp");`
```

3) Use your logger

```
 EXAMPLE: `logger.info ("something interesting happened");`
```

4) If you include log4j.java and your own log4j.properties in your CLASSPATH, then you *don't* need to do *anything* else.

Here's a bit more info on using log4j with Tomcat or app servers:

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html
- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_quick_guide.htm

Here's a very simple example program that "does logging", from the above tutorialspoint.com link:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;

public class log4jExample{
  /* Get actual class name to be printed on */
  static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(
                      log4jExample.class.getName());

  public static void main(String[] args)
                throws IOException,SQLException{

     log.debug("Hello this is an debug message");
     log.info("Hello this is an info message");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:Import log4j jar file in your project

Step 2:-Create a Log java file

```
public Log(Class className) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(className.getClass());
        logger.getClass();
        final String LOG_PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME = "log4j.properties";
        props = loadLogFile(LOG_PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME, className);
        //props =getPropsFile(LOG_PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME, className);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
    }

public static Properties loadLogFile(String propertyFile, Class className) {
        //String filePath="";
        try {
            Properties ps = null;

            ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle
                    .getBundle("resource.DbProperties");
            String logPath = bundle.getString("logs.path");
            File filePath = new File(logPath);
            if (!filePath.exists()) {
                filePath.mkdirs();
            }
            props.clone();
            props = getPropsFile(propertyFile, className);
            props.setProperty("info_file_path", filePath.toString());
            //  PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return props;
    }


public void info(String message) {
    logger.info(message);
}

public void warn(String message) {
    logger.warn(message);
}

public void error(String message) {
    logger.error(message);
}

public void fatal(String message) {
    logger.fatal(message);
}

public void printStackTrace(Throwable ex) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
    logger.error("\n" + sw.toString());
}
```

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootCategory=LOGFILE
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=${info_file_path}\\info_Pension_application.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```